# How to clone a GIT repository with JGit successfully?

Tags: java, git, eclipse, java-8, jgit

I'm trying to clone my repository, but I can't do it...

I have this method:

```
    public static void cloneFilesFromRepository(String urlRepository, String localPath) {
        final File localPathFile = new File(localPath);

        try {
            Git.cloneRepository().setURI(urlRepository).setDirectory(localPathFile)
                    .setCredentialsProvider(new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider("user", "password")).call();
        } catch (InvalidRemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TransportException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (GitAPIException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

But when I execute it, I get this error:

[image]

I copy and paste the repository URL and I can access to the repository.

I don't undestand why this is happening to me...

Comment: What does your URI look like? I'd expect it to end with ".get". If you try cloning using the URI from the command line, does that work? (My guess is that you're trying to use a URL like https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime which is the URL for web access, whereas the cloning URI for that would be https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime.git.)

Comment: OMG! It was for that stupid error... You are right, I was trying it with that URL, without *.git* extension... Thanks ♥